# Parse Output from BackupPC with PHP

Tags: php, parsing

i try to parse the output from "BackupPC_serverMesg status hosts".

The output i get:

```
Got reply: %Status = (" admin " => {"endTime" => "1645958205","activeJob" => 0,"state" => "Status_idle"},"192.168.1.50" => {"lastGoodBackupTime" => "1645944158","deadCnt" => 0,"reason" => "Reason_nothing_to_do","activeJob" => 0,"state" => "Status_idle","aliveCnt" => 1560,"endTime" => "","needLink" => 0,"startTime" => "1645970401","type" => "incr","userReq" => undef}," trashClean " => {"endTime" => "1642317435","activeJob" => 1,"state" => "Status_link_running"}," admin1 " => {"endTime" => "1645956676","activeJob" => 0,"state" => "Status_idle"});
```

I don´t have a Idea how i can parse it.
I need all from "192.168.1.50".

Do you have i idea how to solve it?

thank you for help

Matze

Comment: Your question is very unclear. What is "BackupPC_serverMesg status hosts"? You say _"The output I get"_... from where, when, how? It's a very odd format. Please add some context.

Comment: Agree with @M.Eriksson , Always provide where you get the output, BTW I use this so Immediately recognize where your question come from.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

As per docs https://backuppc.github.io/backuppc/ BackupPC_serverMesg Commands you always get output in text version of perl hash that you need to be eval() inside Perl, then only you can get JSON format in PHP.

Following is one of the cmds output from hosts:-

```
bin/BackupPC_serverMesg status jobs
bin/BackupPC_serverMesg status hosts
bin/BackupPC_serverMesg status info
bin/BackupPC_serverMesg status queues
```

I wrote some code to parse this output string in PHP

```
<?php //php 7.2.24

$code = 'Got reply: %Status = (" admin " => {"endTime" => "1645958205","activeJob" => 0,"state" => "Status_idle"},"192.168.1.50" => {"lastGoodBackupTime" => "1645944158","deadCnt" => 0,"reason" => "Reason_nothing_to_do","activeJob" => 0,"state" => "Status_idle","aliveCnt" => 1560,"endTime" => "","needLink" => 0,"startTime" => "1645970401","type" => "incr","userReq" => undef}," trashClean " => {"endTime" => "1642317435","activeJob" => 1,"state" => "Status_link_running"}," admin1 " => {"endTime" => "1645956676","activeJob" => 0,"state" => "Status_idle"});';

// Let's fix this to JSON String 

$code = str_replace('Got reply: %Status = ','',$code);
$code = str_replace('(','{',$code);
$code = str_replace(')','}',$code);
$code = str_replace('=>',':',$code);
$code = str_replace(';','',$code);
$code = stripslashes($code);
$code = str_replace('" ', '"',$code);
$code = str_replace(' "', '"',$code);
$code = str_replace('undef', '"undef"',$code);
$code = trim($code);

$data = json_decode($code, true);

print_r($data["192.168.1.50"]);

?>
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [lastGoodBackupTime] => 1645944158
    [deadCnt] => 0
    [reason] => Reason_nothing_to_do
    [activeJob] => 0
    [state] => Status_idle
    [aliveCnt] => 1560
    [endTime] => 
    [needLink] => 0
    [startTime] => 1645970401
    [type] => incr
    [userReq] => undef
)
```

Moreover to do this parse in Perl for all output from logs, check this repo code https://github.com/plepe/backuppc-print-status/blob/master/backuppc-status-json